# Android button with multiple click simple

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i am new in android programming, and i am working on my first application, so i just want to know how every time when i click same button it does some action, for example if i have a button called ( next ) and i want to click on it and an image will appear, this one i did it, but **i want to click on the same button and show another image view in the same activity.**
i have tried some code but with no results

so please if anyone can post a code that explain how i can do it.

Comment: what code do you have already? post what you have and maybe people will be nice enough to offer suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example of code...

Rather than show a random image, it will show a random String. All you need to do is just modify it to show images instead.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] names = {"Joe", "Mark", "Amanda", "Kelly", "Michael", "Jenny"};

    private Button button;

    private TextView name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get our views
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                next(); // show random name
            }
        });
    }

    // Display random name on button click
    private void next() {
        name.setText(names[rand()]);
    }

    // Pick a random number from 0 to names.length
    private int rand() {
        return new Random().nextInt(names.length);
    }

}
```